# Qual a utilidade de indexadores?

Tags: c#, .net

Estava vendo e o `Csharp` possui indexadores. Segundo definição no site da [microsoft:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/6x16t2tx.aspx)

> Os Indexadores permitem que as instâncias de uma classe ou estrutura
>   sejam indexadas apenas como vetores.

Exemplos:

```
internal class Indexador<T>
{
    private T[] array = new T[100];

    public T this[int i]
    {
        get { return array[i]; }
        set { array[i] = value; }
    }
}

Indexador<string> index = new Indexador<string>();
index[0] = "string na posicao 0";
```

E minhas dúvidas são:

- Qual a real utilização dos indexadores?
- Existe algum ganho deperformance ou algo do tipo?
- Em que casos, seria recomendado usar indexadores?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> A utilidade é prover uma sintaxe para acessar, através do índice, itens de um objeto que represente uma coleção.

Digamos que você crie uma classe especializada em manter uma coleção de carros e que você queira obter um carro através do seu índice na coleção.

Se indexadores não estivessem disponíveis, você publicaria na sua classe uma função, por exemplo *getItem*, e para obter um item o consumidor teria que fazer algo assim:

```
Carro carro = carros.getItem(1);
```

Usando indexadores, você pode escrever o código de *getItem* no formato de um indexador, e então o consumidor pode obter um item assim:

```
Carro carro = carros[1];
```

Se a sua classe representa uma coleção de maneira semelhante ao que é realizado por um *array*, é natural que você queira acessar os itens do mesmo modo que o faz quando utiliza um *array* - esta é a função dos indexadores em C#.

> Assim, indexadores são apenas uma opção para oferecer uma certa sintaxe aos consumidores da sua classe que represente uma coleção. Se não houvesse indexadores você poderia fazer de outro jeito (publicar uma função *getItem*, por exemplo).

Este recurso era muito utilizado antes de o .Net Framework prover coleções *generics*. Naquela época tínhamos que criar uma nova classe cada vez que quiséssemos uma coleção especializada em um tipo em particular e usar indexadores nos permitia oferecer a mesma sintaxe oferecida pelas coleções nativas do framework.

Quanto à performance, não faz nenhuma diferença usar ou não indexadores.

Comment: Uma dúvida @caffé , esse `getItem(1)` seria uma função para 'buscar' o item manualmente?

Comment: Então indexadores servem apenas para chamar um item que está dentro de uma coleção pelo seu índice. Não há nenhum ganho em utilizar indexadores?

Comment: Sim, @HStackOverflow. Mas veja que o uso de indexadores não te libera de implementar manualmente a função que entrega o item - os indexadores apenas te permitem prover outra sintaxe para o consumidor acessar estes itens. De um jeito ou de outro você terá que escrever na sua classe o código que entrega o item. Exato, MeuChapeu. O ganho está em oferecer uma sintaxe bacana - não há outro ganho.