# É possível retornar uma variável de uma classe orientada a objeto sem utilizar uma função?

Tags: java

Não sei se existe essa possibilidade. Segue um código para auxiliar na pergunta:

```
public class Square
{
    int side;

    public Square(int side)
    {
        this.side = side;
    }

    int getArea()
    {
        return side * side;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Square square = new Square(5);

        System.out.println("Tamanho do lado: " + square + " / Area: " + square.getArea());
    }

}
```

Saída:

> Tamanho do lado: colecoes.Square@15db9742 / Area: 25

É possível sair dessa forma, sem utilizar uma função `get`?

> Tamanho do lado: 5 / Area: 25

Comment: Sobrescreva o método `toString` da classe `Square` e implemente para retornar uma string da forma que está querendo exibir.

Comment: @renan mas nesse caso está retornando do mesmo jeito, certo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implemente na sua classe:

```
public String toString() {
    return side;
}
```

O resto do código pode ficar como está.

O que acontece é que o método `toString()` é chamado para converter seu objeto em string quando você o concatena com outros valores no método `System.out.println`. Como você não fez ainda uma implementação do método, o *toString* da classe pai é chamado, e o que ele faz é mostrar o nome da classe mais a referência para o objeto (que é o output que você está vendo no console).

Talvez esta solução não seja uma boa idéia no sentido de expressividade do código, mas vai fazer exatamente o que você está buscando. Deve haver solução melhor, mas daí você precisa explicar sua intenção.

## Edit:

Esclarecido que a idéia é que o atributo *side* é de fato a representação do objeto, tal qual a cadeia de caracteres é a representação de um objeto String, então usar o método *toString* desta maneira é uma implementação correta.

E há outra maneira de representar um objeto por um de seus atributos sem ter que invocar explicitamente este atributo ou o seu *getter*? **Não**, em Java não há.

Exemplos deste recurso em outras linguagens seriam a propriedade *default* do VB e a sobrecarga de operadores do C#, mas o Java não tem este recurso. Os tipos do próprio Java (String, Integer, Long...) fazem isso usando recursos do compilador e da VM, e não recursos da linguagem. Ou seja: você não tem como alcançar o mesmo resultado em uma classe sua.

Comment: Não sabia que era possível sobrescrever toString() +1. Mas minha duvida ainda persiste pois ainda tenho de utilizar uma função para apresentar a variável daquela classe, digamos que a variável "represente" aquela classe. Essa minha duvida veio com a classe String, quando você cria uma new String("abc") e printa ela, no console resulta em um "abc", sem a necessidade de uma função para apresentar esse valor. A expressividade do código realmente abaixa, a dúvida é apenas aprendizado.

Comment: Cara, o Java faz isso com o tipo String usando "mágica", ele não usa recursos da própria linguagem. Ou seja: você não pode reproduzir esta técnica nas suas próprias classes. Em VB.Net, por exemplo, você pode definir uma propriedade default e em C# você pode usar sobrecarga de operadores para fazer esse tipo de coisa, mas ainda assim estará escrevendo um método - mas em Java você só tem o toString mesmo para representar o objeto. @IagoCoutinhoCampos

Comment: @IagoCoutinhoCampos Só uma pequena correção: escrevi "VB.Net" por vício, mas é o VB que suporta propriedade *default* com a característica de representar o objeto. Propriedade *default* no VB.Net é outra coisa (equivalente à [propriedade indexada do C#](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/66268/14584)).

Answer (score 5):

Sim é possível:

```
class Square {
    public int side;
    public int area;
    public Square(int side) {
        this.side = side;
        area = side * side;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Square square = new Square(5);
        System.out.println("Tamanho do lado: " + square.side + " / Area: " + square.area);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/ng52bn). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/dwsimool-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Class/Square.java).

A classe orientada a objeto ou não pode ter métodos e não funções. Elas podem ter campos públicos também. Nesse caso você pode pegar o valor existe dele sem um método. Foi o que fiz com o atributo `area`.

Isso tem uma dificuldade, nada grave, pode ser o que deseja mesmo. Sempre que o valor do lado mudar por alguma razão, incluindo aí a construção, esse atributo precisa ser atualizado para que sempre que alguém pegá-lo tenha o valor correto.

Note que o outro atributo `side` usado na classe não tem um modificador de visibilidade, o ideal é sempre explicitar. Se deseja que ele seja privado (só a classe pode acessá-lo) declare como `private`. Se quiser que qualquer parte da aplicação acesse seu valor declare como `public`, como eu fiz no atributo `area`. No caso coloquei pública para dar acesso, como parece ser o que deseja, apesar do exemplo não estar correto.

No uso no momento de pedir o lado, não usei o objeto como um todo, usei esse atributo `square.side`.

Algumas pessoas consideram que é errado acessar atributos diretamente sem ter um método para dar o acesso indireto. Depende da aplicação faz todo sentido fazer isso mesmo. Mas há casos que é um exagero e usar um método extra só serve para atrapalhar. Veja mais em [Propriedade Vs variáveis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/133924/101) (é C#, mas o uso de *getter* e  *setter* é igual).

Idealmente o método `main()` deveria estar em outra classe.

Embora tenha algumas recomendações de uso do `toString()` eu não faria isso para retornar o lado. Mandar imprimir o objeto e mostrar só a informação do lado dele, não parece adequada. Mesmo que seja nesse exemplo, se mudar a composição da classe vai dar problema. Tem que conceituar certo as coisas e implementar de acordo com o conceito, caso contrário uma manutenção faria o código não ser mais adequado.

Tentando exemplificar pegando o exemplo no comentário na resposta do Caffé:

Se você cria uma variável `exemplo` do tipo `String`. Se mandar imprimir apenas `exemplo`, ela imprimirá o texto "contido" na variável. Ou seja, quando manda imprimir a variável você quer que imprima exatamente a *string*. Como o texto está representado internamente não importa. Nesse caso o que está sendo impresso está conceitualmente correto.

Se você tem uma variável `square` do tipo `Square`, ou seja tem um quadrado nele, se mandar imprimir `square`, espera-se que imprima o quadrado, seja lá o que isso signifique. Se mandar imprimir apenas o lado do quadrado é uma representação errada do que é o quadrado. Aí vai usar esperando que imprima o lado, um dia precisa mudar e tudo o que existia não funciona mais. Esse problema ocorre porque está conceitualmente errado.

Além disso a pergunta fala em não utilizar uma função, o `toString()` é uma função (método usando a terminologia correta).

Comment: Como havia dito para @Caffé a dúvida é mero aprendizado, realmente reduz a compreensão do código. Como você disse, o método main deveria estar em outra classe, imagine que fosse esse o caso e a variavel

Comment: Apertei [Enter] sem querer... e a variável side fosse privada, é possivel fazer esse tipo de operacão (square1 + square2), cada um com o lado 5 resultando em 10?

Comment: Ou isso torna tudo muito complexo e desnecessário a ponto de descartar esse tipo de coisa?

Comment: Não dá por limitação técnica, além do conceito errado. Somar dois quadrados (que não faz sentido) é diferente de somar os lados de dois quadrados. Não é questão de ser complexo, é questão de ser errado. Mesmo em aprendizado, não é o ideal fazer isso. Mesmo que fosse tecnicamente viável.

Comment: Não creio que seja um conceito errado. O C# suporta isso através da sobrecarga de operadores. É claro que o exemplo em questão pode não justificar, mas o AP esclareceu o objetivo dele.